# Querying 100k records to 5 records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a requirement in such a way that it should join two tables with more than 100k records in one table and just 5 records in another table as shown below

```
   Employee                              Dept                     Result
        id   Name    deptid               deptid   Name            Name     deptid   Name
        1    Jane     1                     1     Science          Jane      1     Science
        2    Jack     2                     2      Maths           Dane      1     Science
        3    Dane     1                     3     Biology          Jack      2      Maths
        4    Drack    3                     4      Social          Drack     3     Biology
        5    Drim                           5     Zoology          Kery      4      Social
        6    Drum     5                                            Drum      5     Zoology
        7    Krack                                                      
        8    Kery     4                                                 
        . 
        . 
        100k
```

Which join need to be used to get the query in an better way to perform to get the result as shown.
I just want the query to join with other table from employee table only which has dept which i thought of below query but wanted to know is there any better way to do it.

```
Select e.name,d.deptid,d.Name from 
(Select deptid,Name from Employee where deptid IS NOT NULL) A 
and dept d where A.deptid=d.deptid;
```

Comment: syntax error at `and dept ...`

Comment: remove and and execute

Answer (score 1):

Firstly not sure why you are performing your query the way you are. Should be more like

```
SELECT A.name, D.deptid,D.Name 
FROM Employee A
INNER JOIN dept D
ON A.deptid = D.deptid
```

No need of the `IS NOT NULL` statement.

If this is a **ONE TIME or OCCASIONAL thing** and performance is key (not a permanent query in your DB) you can leave out the join altogether and do it using `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
   A.name, A.deptid,
   CASE 
      WHEN A.deptid = 1 THEN "Science"
      WHEN A.deptid = 2 THEN "Maths"
      ...[etc for the other 3 departments]...
   END as Name
FROM Employee A
```

If this is to be **permanent** and performance is key, simply try applying an INDEX on the foreign key `deptid` in the `Employee` table and use my first query above.